# Extracting sub string in quotes from a column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I need to replace special characters or i need to extract string within special quotes. I tried already df.replace but its not working.

I have df like this

```
b'rgcr8fpzpx1s7x4a'
b'ue98rkzajy64hrbw'
b'u1u5ucr56y9d8rn4'
```

I need to get output like this:

```
rgcr8fpzpx1s7x4a
 ue98rkzajy64hrbw
 u1u5ucr56y9d8rn4
```

Comment: Post the code you are trying.   Thanks!

Comment: Seems like byte strings to me. Can't you [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/9758194) them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use extract with a regex:

```
df[0].str.extract("b\'(.*)\'")
```

Output:

```
                  0
0  rgcr8fpzpx1s7x4a
1  ue98rkzajy64hrbw
2  u1u5ucr56y9d8rn4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just curuious that when ever i try to use this into my main dataframe then i loose all the values. For example you said column name '0'  so it should be `df[0] = df[0].str.extract("b\'(.*)\'")` but it removed my all the data... am i doing any mistake?

Comment: You need to replace the 0 with your actual column name in your dataframe.  I just copied the data from this question and createded a dataframe with the first column of 0.  Hence, I am using 0.  Please use your actual column header in you dataframe.

Comment: yes ofcourse that i know and i am using my own column name :) But once i use it, i lose my all the data... Its converted the all values 'NaN' in that column. This is what i used `df['uuid: Participant identifier'] = df['uuid: Participant identifier'].str.extract("b\'(.*)\'")`

Comment: You can use `fillna(df['uuid: Participant identifier'])` to back fill those Nan with the original values that don't match that pattern.  You might need to adjust the regex to get your data match.  I am using what you have in this question as a test.

Answer (score 1):

Those values seems to be like byte string, try converting to str.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x : x.decode())

0    rgcr8fpzpx1s7x4a
1    ue98rkzajy64hrbw
2    u1u5ucr56y9d8rn4
Name: col, dtype: object
```